# Add transparent color layer to b&w image using ImageMagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, gm

[image: Red Alpha Layer]

I'm trying to take a black and white image and add a red transparent layer on top. Something similar to the image. Does anyone know how I can do this using ImageMagick in Node using gm?

Comment: If the red layer is transparent, you won't be able to see it! Where does the white wording come from in your example - why hasn't that gone red?

Comment: In imagemagick I would go with a -blend or a -colorize but I do not know what that would be in gm; but it should give you something to search for.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Bonzo suggestion and used blend. With Node gm you can call ImageMagick methods directly.

```
const gm = require('gm');
const im = gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true });

im()
.command('composite')
.in('-blend', '100x100')
.in('-gravity', 'center')
.in('/tmp/top.png')
.in('/tmp/bottom.png').toBuffer('PNG',function (err, buffer) { }
```